# Android 7 - Set Proxy Programmatically

Tags: java, android, networking, proxy, wifi

I'm trying to set the Wifi proxy programmatically in Android 7 but havent been able to get a working solution. It seems like they have changed

What I've tried so far:

- Using a solution for Android > 7 but they obv. didnt work due to the changes implemented in Android 6 that you can only change WiFi configurations you have created yourself
- Try [this](https://github.com/lonelydeveloper97/android-proxy-changing) and adapting it for Nougat (changing the Api requirements to 25) but it just doesnt do anything, no exceptions no nothing. It seems like it worked but the proxy is not there (wifi doesnt even reconnect)

Is there any way to do what I want in 7? A few classes I should look into/tips would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I Had test this Library : https://github.com/lonelydeveloper97/android-proxy-changing;

IT work  from  android  4.0  ~  android 5.0 ;
r Jelly Bean, Kitkat, Lolipop.

Android Android 6.0  doesn't work;